Explicit computation for the coefficients of the intertwining operator
In the following note by Casselman https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf page 74, proposition 9.3.2, for the group $G=SL_{2}$ he computed explicitly the coefficients of the intertwining operator on spherical vectors of the unramified principal series.
In Arthur's the paper "Harmonic analysis of tempered distributions on semisimple Lie groups of real rank one" page 42, a similar intertwining operator $M(\Lambda)$ is defined and is used to study the functional equation of the Eisenstein integral for spherical functions.
My question: is there a similar explicit computation of the intertwining operator over $\mathbb{R}$ for $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ which is parallel to Casselman's computation for p-adic $SL_{2}$? which should be related to the explicit computation of the Plancherel measure for spherical principal series and maybe contained in Harish-Chandra's work.

Actually, a similar explicit computation at the Archimedean place for $\mathrm{SL}_{2}$ can also be found in the following note by Casselman: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Irr.pdf.
The coefficient $c_{s,n}$ of the intertwining operator on the basis vector $\varepsilon_{s}^{n}$ is given in (11.5):
$$c_{s,n}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}\right)^{s+1}\left(\frac{x+i}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}\right)^{n}dx.$$
Then Casselman computes this coefficient in terms of Gamma functions:
$$c_{s,n}=\frac{2^{1-s}\pi\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(\frac{s+1+n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{s+1-n}{2})},$$
in particular
$$c_{s,0}=\frac{\pi^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{s+1}{2})}=\frac{\zeta_{\mathbb{R}}(s)}{\zeta_{\mathbb{R}}(s+1)},$$
which is similar to the $p$-adic case.
